# PHP filter abbreviations world capital case

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am looking code to change abbreviations condition.

```
u.s. should become U.S.

I.n.d. should become I.N.D.

m.l.A. should become M.L.A.

b.s.s.P. should become B.S.S.P.
```

in a string any word found like this it should be changed to Capital letters.

Comment: We not gonna do the work for you. What have you tried? Show us some of your attempts and we will guide you from there...

Comment: @Rob string = "Now i am in i.N.d. and I am m.l.a. and i lives in u.s. now i am going to a.p. to take exam of R.a.s.t."  output shoud be like this Output = "Now i am in I.N.D. and I am M.L.A. and i lives in U.S. now i am going to A.P. to take exam of R.A.S.T."

Comment: In cases of no code, we expect at least a pseudo-code to be put up. How do you think you can make this work? Some effort?

Comment: @DeepanshuGarg atleast show some efforts

Comment: Yes we can make a case like there should be at least 2 letter in word.  abbreviations  word should have at least dot(.) after letter Like in a stirng m.l.a. or U.s.

Comment: @DeepanshuGarg: What have you tried?

Comment: strtoupper() ? http://php.net/strtoupper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "u.s.";

if (preg_match('/^([A-Za-z]\.){2,}$/', $str)) {
    $str = strtoupper($str);
}
```

Comment: yes but it is changing every letter have dot(.) i am looking there should be at least 2 letter like u.s. or M.l.a

Comment: OK Updated answer, see the `{2,}` part? That means it must match a letter followed by a dot at least twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex` to detect if the word has dots. And if it does, convert it to uppercase using `strtoupper()`.